# How to get all value in php mysql in a ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample data

```
product (ID, name)
         1 | 'iPhone'
         2 | 'iPad'
         3 | 'iWatch'
product_meta (ID, product_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
               1      1         image   iPhone.png       
               2      2         view        123
```

And using query:

```
SELECT p.*, m.*
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN product_meta AS m ON m.product_id = p.ID
WHERE p.ID = 1
GROUP BY p.ID
```

How to get all value to result is

```
product(ID, name, image, view) =>  1 | iPhone | iPhone.png | 123
```

Comment: Should your sample data have product_id = 1 for both records in product_meta?  If not, how does iPhone with product_id 1 relate to view 123?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your sample data is incorrect and you're trying to `PIVOT` your results, you can use `MAX` with `CASE` for this:

```
select p.id, 
   p.name, 
   max(case when pm.meta_key = 'image' then pm.meta_value end) image,   
   max(case when pm.meta_key = 'view' then pm.meta_value end) view
from product AS p
    left join product_meta AS pm ON pm.product_id = p.ID
where p.ID = 1
group by p.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like select table1.column1, table2.column2 from .......... rest of query.

Comment: if you are using wordpress, don't re-invent wheel, use direct wwp query, http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

Based on the same assumption as sgeddes:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.name, mimage.meta_value, mview.meta_value
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN product_meta AS mimage
    ON mimage.product_id = p.id AND mimage.meta_key = 'image'
LEFT JOIN product_meta AS mview
    ON mview.product_id = p.id AND mview.meta_key = 'view'
WHERE p.id = 1
```